# Show imported waypoints in table of contents (QGIS)

Tags: qgis, gps

I collect data with a garmin handheld GPS, and then import said data into GIS software. For a specific project, I need to manipulate the buffers for individual points that Ive collected.

Is there a way to showcase each point in the table of contents? For now, they all show up as one layer... but I would like to express different symbologies for each one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you apply a symbology on your layer (like '**categorized**') each individual point will appear in the "table of content". But i fear, depending on the size of your dataset, that it won't be very 'ergonomic' ...

*(In case u use **symbology/categorized** you have to choose one of your point's attribute to be considered as unique identifier (time ?))*

Comment: I’m working on an irrigation project where I plant on indicating where each sprinkler head is located. I plan on adding attributes related to spray distance, zone, and spray pattern. I would group each sprinkler by zone, then individually create buffers to have an accurate depiction of coverage. Im going to attempt categorizing it.